# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I want to check if the address record is already exists or not
and I am using simple query which should will return the value of existed records in database but instead of that it uses the keyword to search for columns
this is my  code :

```
$address=$_POST['billing_address_2'];
$query = "select * from shipping_info WHERE address=$address";
$st2  = $con->prepare($query);
        $st2->execute();
```

this is the exact error message :
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ffff' in 'where clause'.
note :
'ffff' is the value of $address variable

Comment: Use parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you didn't put quotes around `$address`.

But you should use a parametrized query.

mysqli:

```
$address=$_POST['billing_address_2'];
$query = "select * from shipping_info WHERE address=?";
$st2  = $con->prepare($query);
$st2->bind_param("s", $address);
$st2->execute();
```

PDO:

```
$address=$_POST['billing_address_2'];
$query = "select * from shipping_info WHERE address=:address";
$st2  = $con->prepare($query);
$st2->bindParam(":address", $address);
$st2->execute();
```

Comment: @Barmer thanks for your answer  ,i am new to php